# Gluon Charm 4.0.0 GlassPane not modal anymore?

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I used following code to install a `Layer` in the `GlassPane` and show it:

```
glassPane.getLayers().add(myLayer);
MobileApplication.getInstance().addLayerFactory("myLayer", ()-> myLayer);

MobileApplication.getInstance().showLayer("myLayer");
```

While on `Charm 3.0.0` the layer was showing modal on top of the current view, on `Charm 4.0.0` the layer isn't modal anymore.
So is there a build in function to show it modal again, or do we have to use an `EventFilter` ?

**EDIT:**

[ProgressLayer complete code](https://github.com/j-ns/Orienteering/blob/master/Orienteering/src/main/java/com/jns/orienteering/control/ProgressLayer.java)
(not adapted to Charm 4.0.0)

Simplified code of ProgressLayer:

```
public class ProgressLayer extends Layer {

   private static final GlassPane GLASS_PANE = MobileApplication.getInstance().getGlassPane(); 
   private String layerName;

   private StackPane              root;
   private Circle                 clip;
   private double                 size;

     public ProgressLayer(Node icon, double radius, String layerName) {
        setAutoHide(false);
        this.layerName = layerName;
        size = radius * 2; 

        ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator();
        progress.setStyle("-fx-color:#ff9100");
        progress.setRadius(radius);

        root = new StackPane(progress);

        if (icon != null) {
          icon.getStyleClass().add("progress-icon");

          clip = new Circle(radius-1);
          icon.setClip(clip);

          root.getChildren().add(icon);
        }

        getChildren().add(root);
        GLASS_PANE.getLayers().add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void layoutChildren() {
        root.setVisible(isShowing());
        if (!isShowing()) {
          return;
        }

        root.resizeRelocate((GLASS_PANE.getWidth() - size) / 2, (GLASS_PANE.getHeight() - size) / 2, size, size);
        if (clip != null) {
          clip.setLayoutX(root.getWidth() / 2 -1);
          clip.setLayoutY(root.getHeight() /2 -1);
        }
    }

    public void setOnCancelled(EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler) {
        root.setOnMouseClicked(handler);
   }
}
```

[image]

As long as an operation is running, the progressLayer will be shown, and you are not able to interrupt the operation or hide the layer, unless you press the purple icon in the center:

```
progressLayer.setOnCancelled(e -> hideLayer(progressLayer.getLayerName()));
```

And here is the problem. When `root` doesn't use the whole screensize, UI controls that are not covered by `root` like buttons e.g. can be activated. This behaviour is in contrast to Gluon Charm 3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `myLayer.setAutoHide(false)`?

According to [JavaDoc](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/Layer.html#autoHideProperty--) for `autoHideProperty()`:

> Represents whether this Layer should hide when it is clicked outside its bounds - by default this is true.

**EDIT**

This is a small project that works for me:

*build.gradle*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.1.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.testmodal.TestModal'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.0.1'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.0.0'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

*TestModal*

```
public class TestModal extends MobileApplication {

    public static final String BASIC_VIEW = HOME_VIEW;
    public static final String BASIC_LAYER = "My Layer";

    @Override
    public void init() {
        addViewFactory(BASIC_VIEW, () -> new BasicView(BASIC_VIEW));
        addLayerFactory(BASIC_LAYER, () -> new ProgressLayer(BASIC_LAYER));
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(Scene scene) {
        Swatch.BLUE.assignTo(scene);
        ((Stage) scene.getWindow()).getIcons().add(new Image(TestModal.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));
    }

    class ProgressLayer extends Layer {

        private final Node root;

        public ProgressLayer(String layerName) {
            setAutoHide(false);

            ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator();
            progress.setRadius(100);

            root = new StackPane(progress);
            getChildren().add(root);
            getGlassPane().getLayers().add(this);

            showingProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
                if (nv) {
                    setBackgroundFade(0.5);
                    PauseTransition p = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));
                    p.setOnFinished(e -> hideLayer(BASIC_LAYER));

                    p.playFromStart();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void layoutChildren() {
            root.resize(getGlassPane().getWidth(), getGlassPane().getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

*BasicView*

```
public class BasicView extends View {

    public BasicView(String name) {
        super(name);

        Button button = new Button("Show Progress");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            MobileApplication.getInstance().showLayer(TestModal.BASIC_LAYER);
        });

        VBox controls = new VBox(button);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        setCenter(controls);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
        appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> System.out.println("Menu")));
        appBar.setTitleText("Basic View");
        appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.SEARCH.button(e -> System.out.println("Search")));
    }
}
```

When I run it, and click on the button, the background fade is set to 0.5 just to see that all the scene is covered by the glass pane, and I can't click on any of the underlying buttons until the layer is hidden via the pause transition.

[image: Layer]

Comment: Yes, I already tried that. I've edited my answer with a simplified version of my layer

Comment: In the previous Charm version I was able to show / hide a layer with the according functions. `layer.show()` still works, while `layer.hide()` doesn't. So I had to use `addLayerFactory()` and `mobileInstance.hideLayer("myLayer")`

Comment: That works for me (it's on top of view, and it is modal, clicking outside of it doesn't hide the layer). What is it that fails to you? And yes, you need to use `addLayerFactory` and `hideLayer`.

Comment: Yes, clicking outside doesn't hide the layer, but the UI controls under the layer can be activated, e.g. when I click a button while the layer is visible the button events get fired

Comment: Ok, as long as the root node covers the complete view, it works perfectly. I've edited my answer again, with my special use case, where it is not working as expected.

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce it now. I've filed an issue on this. You'll need to cover the whole scene or make the underlaying view mouse transparent when the layer is showing.